# What exception is raised when using + on symbols in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

Doing the [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/), in the file `about_symbols` at line 88, I'm not sure of the answer.

This is the code:

```
def test_symbols_cannot_be_concatenated
    # Exceptions will be pondered further farther down the path
    assert_raise(what should i put?) do
      :cats + :dogs
    end
```

Answer (score 6):

The point of the [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/) is to learn by reading and trying things out.

Open up a terminal and start `irb`. Then try using the `+` operator on two symbols. Check the error you get and substitute it as appropriate in the Koans file.

Assuming that your prompt ends in `$`, that will look something like this:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> :cats + :dogs
```

The answer you need will be clear pretty quickly in the error that `irb` spits out.

Answer (score -1):

To go through step by step in case your completely new to Ruby you could try:

1. Open up a terminal
2. Type `irb` at your prompt to get to the interactive ruby prompt

   - This is where you can quickly try out different Ruby things
3. Type the command in question `:cats + :dogs`
4. Review the output which will look like

> ```
> NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for :cats:Symbol
>   from (irb):1
> ```

The name of the exception thrown which is what you are looking for is the first thing e.g. `NoMethodError`

Comment: Flat out telling him isn't really helping him. At least give him a chance to find his own answer.

Comment: I disagree if you are new to Ruby and using a terminal in general (which I was recently) it can be daunting to just look at a terminal let alone interpret the output. I broke down the output so he can understand what it means and what he is actually looking for. Yes it's great to figure it all out for yourself but he asked a question for an answer not for a further challenge.

Comment: If he's not willing to *try* to read a terminal and interpret it's output, then the Koans are a singularly bad way to try to learn Ruby. The *entire point* of them is that they are an interactive method of `read`, `write`, `run`, `read` and then often `repeat` until you get it.

Comment: Ok well I think we should agree to disagree I think the koans are great and if all the OP requires to get through them is a little help (understanding something that may at first be complicated) from other people then they still serve there purpose just fine.